# Why pointers substraction results in number of elements in between?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the code:

```
int arr[20]{};
int * ptr1=arr, * ptr2=&arr[1];
std::cout<<ptr1<<std::endl<<ptr2<<std::endl<<ptr2-ptr1;
```

Output:

```
0x7fff4003e0d0
0x7fff4003e0d4
1
```

Why it isn't 4 instead?

Comment: Because it is the definition of pointers substraction?

Comment: Because type system.

Comment: Isn't `arr[1]` 1 away from `arr[0]`(`arr`)?

Comment: @MikeCAT Then how can I get the result as 4 in any manner?

Comment: By multiplying by 4?

Comment: @MikeCAT I mean if I do this : cout<<0x7fff4003e0d4 -0x7fff4003e0d0; assuming that there is no any array declaration, then why it is yielding 4 but here it is 1?

Comment: Because `0x7fff4003e0d4 -0x7fff4003e0d0` is just a normal integer aritimetic, not pointer aritimetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it didn't to that you'd just end up dividing the difference by `sizeof(whatever)` all the time. The number of elements is far more useful than the raw difference. When you need the latter, cast the two pointers to `char*` for the subtraction.

Comment: How can I get the result as 4 in any manner?

Comment: "cast the two pointers to `char*` for the subtraction"?

Comment: I mean if I do this : cout<<0x7fff4003e0d4 -0x7fff4003e0d0; assuming that there is no any array declaration, then why it is yielding 4 but here it is 1?